# failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: apt, snap, atom

Whenever I am trying to run an application I encounter this error,
for example running Atom in terminal resulted in this error:

`/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object`

Have anyone has a clue how can I fix this? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

I have tried 
`sudo apt install libdvd-pkg` and `sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386`
 which did not have any result.